# List of links pulled from a jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I'm using an array of images with next/previous functions to navigate through the images. I'd also like to have an unordered list of the individual images so users can click on a specific one, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I could link the images directly, but I'm not sure how to have them show up where the others do when next/previous is clicked.

Array:

```
var myImg= new Array()
  myImg[0]= "Home";
  myImg[1]= "Solutions";
  myImg[2]= "About";
  myImg[3]= "Careers";
  myImg[4]= "Contact";

myImgSrc = "images/";
myImgEnd = ".png"
var i = 0;

function loadImg(){
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[i] + myImgEnd;
}

function prev(){
  if(i<1){
    var l = i
  } else {
    var l = i-=1;
  }
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd;
}

function next(){
  if(i>3){
    var l = i
  } else {
    var l = i+=1;
  }
  document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[l] + myImgEnd;
}

window.onload=loadImg;
```

Markup:

```
<div id="top">
<div class="box">
<p class="l"><a href="#" onClick="prev();">&laquo; Previous Image</a></p>

<ul id="list">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<p class="r"><a href="#" onClick="next();">Next Image &raquo;</a></p>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="container">

<div id="image">
<img name="imgSrc" id="imgSrc" />
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the index of the clicked 'anchor's parent 'li' let it be indexOfLi , use jquery index() or write a javascript function to calculate index.

```
function goToImg(index){
    document.imgSrc.src = myImgSrc + myImg[indexOfLi] + myImgEnd;
    }
```

In jQuery, bind the click event

```
$(document).on('click','#list li a',function(){
    goToImg($(this).parent().index());
    return false; // to prevent default action
    });
```

Please have a look at binding events using javascript and using jQuery.

For on function to work, you have to use ~ jQuery 1.7.2

for earlier versions

```
$('#list li a').click(function(){
    goToImg($(this).parent().index());
    return false; // to prevent default action
    });
```

Comment: please have a look at javascript events and event bindings

Comment: I tried a few variations of your suggestion, but nothing happens. The links still do not go to the image on click.

Comment: did you include jQuery library? if not use eventbinding , create a jsfiddle of the same so that we can take a look.

Comment: The jQuery library is included- as I said, the prev(); and next(); functions work, but the images don't change using the event binding. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mDRy/2/ I can't show the images, but they do work with prev and next. The images show up below this navigation in `<div id="image">
<img name="imgSrc" id="imgSrc" />
</div>
`

Comment: Also change indexOfLi to index in first function as the passed index is accepted into index, not indexOfLi